# disabling textbox for multiple rows dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I create rows dynamically using the event onfocus of d or w field. I got that correct,but the radio button- when i choose dm, **d** should be disabled and cm, **w** should be disabled. I am not sure how to do that. Please help me out

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tvtable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="10%" style="text-align: center;">Type</th>
            <th width="20%" style="text-align: center;">A</th>
            <th width="20%" style="text-align: center;">d</th>
            <th width="20%" style="text-align: center;">w</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="wd0" id="rd" value="dr" />Dm
                <br/>
                <input type="radio" name="wd0" id="rc" value="cr" />Cm</td>
            <td>
                <select id="m0" class="form-control"></select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="form-control c1 amt" type="number" id="w0" name="amt1"  />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="form-control c2 amt" type="number" id="d0" name="amt2"  />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function ()
{
  if ($('#rd').prop('checked'))
  {
    $(".c1").attr("disabled", "disabled");
  }
  else if($('#rc').prop('checked'))
  {
    $(".c2").attr("disabled", "disabled");
  }
  var counter = 0;
  $(document).on("focus", ".amt", function (event)
  {
    counter++;
    var list = '<tr><td><input type="radio" name="wd' + counter + '" id="rd" value="dr" />Dm<br/><input type="radio" name="wd' + counter + '" id="rc" value="cr" />Cm</td><td><select id="m' + counter +
        '" class="form-control "></select></td><td><input class="form-control c1 amt" type="number" id="w' + counter + '" name="amount"  /></td><td><input class="form-control c2 amt" type="number" id="d' + counter + '" name="amount" /></td></tr>';
    $('#tvtable').append(list);
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/A8G5v/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not include jQuery in JSfiddle plus syntax errors.

You are appending checkboxes dynamically, so the `if()..else()` won't work on `document.ready`.

Add a delegated change event.

```
$(document).on('change', ':radio', function () {
    if ($(this).prop('checked') && $(this).val() == 'dr') {
        $(this).parents('tr').find(".c1").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $(this).parents('tr').find(".c2").removeAttr("disabled");
    } else{
        $(this).parents('tr').find(".c2").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $(this).parents('tr').find(".c1").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
});
```

Note : Your code is generating duplicate IDs which wont work for later `append`.

**[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/A8G5v/2/)**

Comment: This code is not working correctly, once i have selected the rd or rc , i m not able to revert back the changes. for the first row its working correctly after that i am not getting it

Comment: Because you have **duplicate IDs**.

Comment: so what is the solution you would propose for this. this is the exact model i am looking for. I am not able to get any other solution. And i need diff ID's since i got to push bulk data at once

Comment: Use a common `data-attribute` or a `class` or assign counter to `id` also

Comment: i have assigned counter to ID, and class is what i am using to enable and disable. I m just running out of solutions

Comment: Its great .  Thanks a lot. Btw , do you know how to retrieve data from db(MYSQL) in php. Edit it in the UI and save the data.?

Comment: No idea. You can ask another question for it